# How to join calculated data with months?

Tags: postgresql

I have regions and months:

```
 80 | San Diego         |      1
 80 | San Diego         |      2
 80 | San Diego         |      3
 80 | San Diego         |      4
 80 | San Diego         |      5
 80 | San Diego         |      6
 80 | San Diego         |      7
 80 | San Diego         |      8
 80 | San Diego         |      9
 80 | San Diego         |     10
 80 | San Diego         |     11
 80 | San Diego         |     12
 74 | Tampa             |      1
 74 | Tampa             |      2
 74 | Tampa             |      3
 74 | Tampa             |      4
 74 | Tampa             |      5
 74 | Tampa             |      6
 74 | Tampa             |      7
 74 | Tampa             |      8
 74 | Tampa             |      9
 74 | Tampa             |     10
 74 | Tampa             |     11
 74 | Tampa             |     12
 64 | Denver            |      1
 64 | Denver            |      2
 64 | Denver            |      3
 64 | Denver            |      4
 64 | Denver            |      5
 64 | Denver            |      6
 64 | Denver            |      7
 64 | Denver            |      8
 64 | Denver            |      9
 64 | Denver            |     10
 64 | Denver            |     11
 64 | Denver            |     12
```

Also I have calculated sums:

```
 74 | Tampa             |     12 | 100
 74 | Tampa             |      6 |  80
 80 | San Diego         |      7 |  50
```

How to join this tables to get:

```
 80 | San Diego         |      1  |
 80 | San Diego         |      2  |
 80 | San Diego         |      3  |
 80 | San Diego         |      4  |
 80 | San Diego         |      5  |  50
 80 | San Diego         |      6  |
 80 | San Diego         |      7  |
 80 | San Diego         |      8  |
 80 | San Diego         |      9  |
 80 | San Diego         |     10  |
 80 | San Diego         |     11  |
 80 | San Diego         |     12  |
 74 | Tampa             |      1  |
 74 | Tampa             |      2  |
 74 | Tampa             |      3  |
 74 | Tampa             |      4  |
 74 | Tampa             |      5  |
 74 | Tampa             |      6  |  80
 74 | Tampa             |      7  |
 74 | Tampa             |      8  |
 74 | Tampa             |      9  |
 74 | Tampa             |     10  |
 74 | Tampa             |     11  |
 74 | Tampa             |     12  | 100
```

As you can see `Denver` should be filtered from first resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function to calculate the total of calculated sums per region (the `c` CTE) and filter regions for which the total is 0. This drops Denver. I assume that the first table is called `t` and the second - `s`.

```sql
with c as
(
 select t.*, s.calc_sum, 
        sum(s.calc_sum) over (partition by t.region_id) total
 from t left outer join s using(region_id, "month")
)
select region_id, region_name, "month", calc_sum 
from c where total > 0 order by region_id desc, "month";
```

See [DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vQYr1XLWfbs9Xpp2sCdTaH/1)

Here is it using `group by`.

```sql
with c1 as
(
 select t.*, s.calc_sum
 from t left outer join s using(region_id, "month")
),
c2 as
(
  select region_id
  from c1
  group by region_id having (sum(calc_sum) > 0)
)
select c1.*
from c1 inner join c2 using (region_id)
order by region_id desc, "month";
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vQYr1XLWfbs9Xpp2sCdTaH/3)

Comment: Hello, thanks. Is it possible to complete this using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Well, I am not sure.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I have updated the answer with a `GROUP BY` version. Yet I better like the window function version.